# Visual Studio Extension certificate validation fails for Votive (Wix)

Tags: visual-studio, wix, certificate, certutil, votive

Installing Votive, an extension for Wix - Windows Installer fails for both Votive 2017 and Votive 2019 Visual Studio extension. The reason is a certificate validation error. How can you update your root certificates and install the Visual Studio extension without getting certificate validation error?

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to install Votive using the following Powershell commands to refresh the root certificates with Windows Update.

```
mkdir c:\certs #temporary folder where the certificates will be installed/updated
cd c:\certs 
certutil.exe -generateSSTFromWU roots.sst
$sstStore = ( Get-ChildItem -Path C:\certs\roots.sst )
$sstStore | Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

The -generateSSTFromWU option downloads all certificates into a .sst file that can be opened with MMC by double clicking, but I ran the Powershell commands listed above to also get all certificates installed.

After doing this, Votive extension installed and I could open the Visual Studio solution with the .wixproj Wix project inside. This worked for both Votive 2017 and Votive 2019.

It is possible to install WixToolset with Chocolatey, but I needed the Visual Studio Extension - called Votive.